# Rough paths, unparametrized path space, and Kontsevich's moduli space of stable maps

Tags: moduli-spaces, noncommutative-algebra, rough-paths, regularity-structures

Let $X$ be a manifold. Modulo reparametrization, the path space of $X$ is a groupoid $\Pi_X$. In Kapranov's "Free Lie Algebroids and the Space of Paths", Kapranov constructs an associated Lie algebroid $\mathcal{P}_X$. In the case $X$ is in algebraic variety, Kapranov develops an algebro-geometric model for the space of constant paths into $X$ (known as the formal neighborhood $\hat{\Pi}_X$). Remarkably, he constructs a morphism from a formal neighborhood of $\overline{M}_{0,2}(X,\beta)$ (for non-algebraic geometers, this is the moduli space of stable maps into $X$ with source curve of genus 0 with two marked points). In this interpretation, the marked points $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the start and end points of the paths. Furthermore, this moduli space is defined up to a reparametrization analogous to reparametrizing paths. Now, if $y$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-point of $X$, and $\gamma$ a path in $X$ which lies in a coordinate patch $\{x_i\}$, he associates to $\gamma$ a formal power series $E_{\gamma} = \sum_{p=0} ^ {\infty} \sum_{i_1,...,i_p} ^ {n} \left(\int_\gamma ^ {\rightarrow}dx_{i_1}...dx_{i_p}\right)D_{i_1}...D_{i_p}$ where $D_i$ are sections of $\mathcal{P}_X$ and $\int_{\gamma} ^ {\rightarrow} dx_{i_1}...dx_{i_p}$ are Chen's iterated integrals. Chen's fundamental shuffle relations allow one to think of $E_{\gamma}$ as a groupoid-like object, and this structure is used to construct a morphism of stacks $\phi:\Pi_X \rightarrow \hat{M}_{\beta}$ where $\hat{M}_{\beta}$ is a formal neighbhorhood of the moduli space of stable maps.

Question: given that in the definition of rough paths, Chen's relation is $\textit{postulated}$, is there a hope of directly relating rough paths to the moduli space of stable maps with two marked points?